# WordPress: Unable to overwrite parent theme file via child theme

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I'm having issue in overwriting parent theme file via child theme. Normally I copy parent theme file to child theme by following same file structure/path and it works. But this time it is not working. I'm not sure, what is the problem...

The parent file is located at:

```
wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/assets/js/FILENAME.js
```

and I put at this path in child theme:

```
wp-content/themes/CHILDTHEME/assets/js/FILENAME.js
```

Same problem on this file:

Parent Path:

```
wp-content/themes/THEMENAME/includes/FILE.php
```

Child Path:

```
wp-content/themes/CHILDTHEME/includes/FILE.php
```

I'm pretty sure, I'm missing something technical but I'm unable to figure out. Looking for help!

Answer (score 0):

Child theme doesn't override css/js files, to achieve that, You will need to dequeue these scripts in the child functions.php file, You need to get the script handle name that parent theme uses to enqueue it.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
  wp_dequeue_script( 'script-handle-name' );
}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Child theme only overrides the template files [Template Hirarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

To override a php file, There are two conditions:

1) If the file function you want to override is hooked to action / filter then create a function in the child theme functions.php file with a different name and hook it with a higher priority.

2) If you want to override the function itself, you can recreate the function in the child theme functions.php with the same name only if The function is created in the parent theme with the condition.

```
if ( ! function_exists ( 'my_function' ) ) {
    function my_function() {
    }
}
```

otherwise, It will raise a fatal error.

Comment: Thanks @Ash0ur, it works for the script but above both methods doesn't work for php problem. Is there any alternative method for that? Just FYI, the php function I need to override is not hooked to action and I tried to use above function (if function not exist...) and it didn't worked! :(